# Xcode: the platform is not currently connected

Tags: c, xcode, apple-m1

I get this error when I build my console application (C language) in Xcode.

```
Could not launch “teszt”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: the platform is not currently connected
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-11-02 18:46:50 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "the platform is not currently connected";
}
```

I don't really know how to move forward. I tried to read after but I couldn't find any concrete solution.

Answer (score 5):

In my case problem was that Xcode was started in Rosetta mode. I turned off Rosetta mode and everything became fine

Comment: That was my problem, too.

Comment: To turn off Rosetta mode, on your Mac, go to Applications > Xcode, then right-click, select "Get Info", and you'll see a checkbox under "General" to "Open using Rosetta". Remove the check.